# Updating url path with selected tab

Tags: html, angular

I have a list of menu items and when i click on them the display content changes and that all works fine but i also want to be able to update the url path with the selected tab and i wanted to know how can i update my current list to use any available given angular 2 feature.

current code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li [class.active]="isTab('home')">
                <a (click)="setTab('home')">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li [class.active]="isTab('contacts')">
                <a (click)="setTab('contacts')">Contacts</a>
            </li>
....
</ul>

<home-view *ngIf="isTab('home')"></home-view>
<contacts-view *ngIf="isTab('contacts')"></contacts-view>
...
```

I would like so whenever i click on either home or contacts tab that the url path gets updated to ..../home or ..../contacts so the user will be able to navigate back to it if they were to navigate away.

I am using angular 2 with typescript

Answer (score 1):

> This is not a proper way , if you want the url and nvaigation link to
>   work
>
> Please go for route instead of using ngIf to show hide compoenents

```
routes = [
    ...
    {    path : 'home' , compoenent : HomeComponent },
    {    path : 'contacts' , compoenent : ContactsComponent },
    ...
];
```

Template Side :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" >About</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active" >Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> To add a certain class based on if a certain route is active, we can
>   use `routerLinkActive`

For more detail : **[Watch this](https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/router-links-active)**

Answer (score 0):

You should resort to routes then.

i.e. in app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '',         redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'home',         compoennt: HomeViewComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: 'contacts',     compoennt: ContactsViewComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: '**',           component: HomeViewComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [ 
    ...,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false }),
  ],
  exports: [...]
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Then in your component html, add a router-outlet

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li [class.active]="isTab('home')">
                <a (click)="setTab('home')">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li [class.active]="isTab('contacts')">
                <a (click)="setTab('contacts')">Contacts</a>
            </li>
....
</ul>
<router-outlet>
```

and in your component ts you can control the route by inject router

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

 setTab(newTab: string) {
    this.router.navigate([newTab]);
  }
```